# Apollo react useQuery cache working strange

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client, react-apollo-hooks

I have a component with a data list. Also, I have another with mutation for item element. After the update, cached is updated, but list stays not update until rerender component.

List component query:

```
 export const categoriesQuery = gql`
    query Categories {
      podcastCategories {
        id
        regions
        title
        subcategories {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `
```

I use `useQuery` for fetch data:

```
const categoriesResults = useQuery<Categories>(categoriesQuery)
console.log('categoriesReults', categoriesResults)
```

Also, I have other component `CategoriesItem.tsx` with mutation:

```
export const podcastCategoryUpdate = gql`
   mutation PodcastCategoryUpdate($categoryId: String!, $category: CategoryInput!) {
     podcastCategoryUpdate(categoryId: $categoryId, category: $category) {
       coverImageUrl
       coverImageId
       color
       id
       svg
       subcategories {
         categoryId
         id
         title
         translations {
           region
           title
         }
       }
       regions
       title
       translations {
         region
         title
       }
     }
   }
 `
```

I use `useMutation` hook to update it:

```
const updateFn = useMutation<PodcastCategoryUpdate, PodcastCategoryUpdateVariables>(podcastCategoryUpdate)
```

Problem is that cache is updated, but list component did not use recent cache version.

Comment: same here. did you figure out how to get it work?

Comment: I changed caching policy for apollo client

Comment: but, `useMutation` doesn't return a function. it returns a tuple of `[MutationFn, MutationResult]`

Comment: I'm getting this same issue, did anyone figure out how to get it working? @EdgarasKarka how'd you change the caching policy?

Comment: I suggest to check the resolver return entity. Because the mutation response entity must have the same type as a query entity. It can be one of the reasons why it's not working